# aws boto3 passing json as parameters went wrong

Tags: json, string, amazon-web-services, boto3, gateway

I'm working on something with python boto3 to use aws api gateway to trigger step functions. I have some problem with the test_invoke_method() function, the body parameter to be specific.

```
response = apigateway.test_invoke_method(
        restApiId='**xxxx**xx**',
        resourceId='**xxxx**xxxx',
        httpMethod='POST',
        body='{"input": "{"type": "public", "value": 22}", "name": "MyExecution222", "stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-2:707900832957:stateMachine:Step_Function_Test1111"}')
```

It just couldn't work, and the output indicates that the

```
"input": "{"type": "public", "value": 22}"
```

has problem, it works when I change it into

```
"input": "{}"
```

I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Did your deploy your API layout? e.g. create_model/resource/rest_api. Or use the console do it : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-from-example.html

Comment: I could use the console and invoke the method, it works. But not working via python call......